# How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?

Tags: math-mode, braces, cases

How can I get a brace on the right, not the left, to group cases, using `cases`? (I know actual cases look better with the brace on the left, but the items I need to group are not literally cases. They are a set of steps in an algorithm which I want to consider as an item.)

The following puts the brace on the left. All I need to do is to flip it to the right.

```
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a&=bbb\\
c&=ddddddd\\
e&=ffffffffff
\end{cases}
\end{align}
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

use package `mathtools`. There is also a `drcases` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{rcases*}
E = m c^2 & foo \\
\int x-3\, dx & barbaz
\end{rcases*} y=f(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! Loading `mathtools` and changing `cases` to `drcases` works perfectly!

Answer (score 75):

With the help of the `aligned` environment from `amsmath`, you can define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  a &= b + c \\
  d &= e + f + g \\
  h &= i + j + k + l
\end{rcases}
\text{ three equations}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. What can I do to have the brace on the left instead? What changed should I make? Thanks.

Comment: @Steeven in that case, you don't need anything special; you can use the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: What if I wan to write a text in body. I have wrote a text in different font ($ \begin{rcases}    ${\sffamily {to love}}$ \\  \end{rcases}$ ) and compiler has written me 'Missing }'. Why and where? Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left.\begin{aligned}
  a&=bbb\\
  c&=ddddddd\\
  e&=ffffff
\end{aligned}\right\} = stuff
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read my answer? :-)

Comment: @Gonzalo yes I did now, you were faster than I. I saw your solution after having formatted my answer. Sorry.