# Add a brace on the left side of a group

Tags: braces, grouping

I can't figure out how to place the brace on the opposite side, that is on the left of the group of equations, when following the answer in this link:

[How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases)

What should be changed in the solution?

Comment: Use `cases*` instead of `rcases*`, the Herbert's answer shoud work then.

Comment: did you read the *question* from your link? :)

Comment: Hahaha :) Well cmhughes, it was a long and tiring night... apparently. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: (Actually correct duplicate should be [conditionals - Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cases`. Load `amsmath` package in the preamble as usual.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
a&=bbb\\
c&=ddddddd\\
e&=ffffffffff
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Also, you can use `equation*` instead of `align*`.

Here is the output.

[image]