# how to code left facing bracket of values with single value to its right?

Tags: brackets, code

How can I make a vector in this form?

[image]

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in two ways: either with the `mathtools` package (needless to load `amsmath`) or with the `blkarray` package. Math tools defines `rcases` and `drcases` environments (the latter is the displaystyle version of the former):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{rcases} -1 \\ \hphantom{-} \vdots \\ -1 \end{rcases}m \qquad
 \begin{blockarray}[t]{c \Right{\}}{\,$ m $}}-1 \\ \hphantom{-} \vdots \\ -1 \end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]