# Align right braces inside subequations

Tags: align, cases, subequations

I am trying to align a set of equations using the right braces.

A similar question is asked here [Align multiple equations within right braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365909/183487)

In my case, I would like to use also subequations to get **(1a)** and **(1b)**.

Till now I was using rcases and the code was similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    &\begin{rcases}
        a &= b + c \\
    d &= e + f + g \\
    h &= i + j + k + l\\
    \end{rcases}&& \quad\text{three equations}\\
   & \begin{rcases}
     m &= n \\
    o &= p*q
    \end{rcases}&& \quad\text{another two equations}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

The following picture indicates with red the changes I would like to have.

[image]

Comment: What you want is not very clear. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 4):

It also can be obtained with nested `aligned` environments, with a better spacing of the `=`  sign.  A variant would patch the `rcases` environment instead, with the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{myrcases}{\thickspace}{%
  $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th{##}$\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathboxR}[2][D]{\eqmakebox[#1][r]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\newcommand{\eqmathboxL}[2][S]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    &\left.\begin{aligned}
        \eqmathboxR{a} &= b + c \\
    \eqmathboxR{d} &= e + f + g \\
   \eqmathboxR{h}&= \eqmathboxL{i + j + k + l}
    \end{aligned}\right\rbrace&\enspace &\text{three equations}\\[1ex]
 & \left. \begin{aligned}
\eqmathboxR{\implies m} & = n \\
 \eqmathboxR{o} & = \eqmathboxL{p*q}
 \end{aligned}\right\rbrace&\enspace &\text{another two equations}
 \end{alignat}
 \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can pseudo align the braces by putting all expressions on the right handside of the `=` signs into boxes of equal width.

The package `eqparbox` serves exactly this purpose.

Unfortunately the different typographical properties of the braces disturbs the look. It should be possible to redefine the brace command that `mathtools` uses in case of the `rcases` environment.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand\EqMathBox[2][x]{%
    \eqparbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        & \begin{rcases}
            \EqMathBox[left]{a}& = \EqMathBox{b + c}         \\
            \EqMathBox[left]{d}& = \EqMathBox{e + f + g}     \\
            \EqMathBox[left]{h}& = \EqMathBox{i + j + k + l \qquad\quad} \\
        \end{rcases}%
        \quad\text{three equations}       &&\\[1em]
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        & \begin{rcases}
            \EqMathBox[left]{m}& = \EqMathBox{n}             \\
            \EqMathBox[left]{o}& = \EqMathBox{p\cdot q}      \\
        \end{rcases}%
        \quad\text{another two equations} &&
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Essentially good, but the second brace is just a bit farther to the right because the *m* in the second group us wider than the beginning parts of either line in the first group.  So both pre-= groups also need to be in equal-sized boxes.  (Or some similar adjustment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your comment! I was to focused on the braces... I will update the code accordingly