# align right braces

Tags: align, braces

I found this latex sample, close to what I need but fail to modify it like I need.
I try to understand how to do, reading about eqparbox package but it doesn't help me more.

I want to make braces on several lines of left text (text 1,2,3,...) with explanations on the right side of the braces (explanation A, B).
I would like to:

- align braces
- remove (1a, 1b, ...)

it only be text, no math or calculus.

here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand\EqMathBox[2][x]{%
 \eqparbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    & \begin{rcases}
        \text{text 1}         \\
        \text{text 2}     \\
        \text{text 3} \\
    \end{rcases}%
    \quad\text{explenation A}       && \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    & \begin{rcases}
        \text{a longer text}             \\
        \text{a quit more longer text}      \\
    \end{rcases}
    \quad\text{explenation B} &&
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \end{document}
```

[here is the origin of the sample](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538061/align-right-braces-inside-subequations)

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE. first question you not employ `eqparbox` (if you like to have braces at the same horizontal positions) , for second: just remove environment `subequations`. See link, which you provided, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the solution below, the main environment `array` is used to add the right braces. Then inner tabular is to gather rows of text with `eqpabox` to make sure all right braces are right-aligned.

In order to apply `\eqparbox` to each row (cell) of `tabular` env., I load `collcell` along with `array` package and defined a custom column which adds a small macro: `\pbox` which in turn applies `\eqparbox`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand\pbox[1]{\eqparbox{alist}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\pbox}l<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \[
    \begin{array}{l @{\quad} l}
      \left.\begin{tabular}{P}
        text 1\\
        text 2\\
        text 3\\
        text 4
      \end{tabular}\right\}
      & \textrm{explanation A} \\
      \left.\begin{tabular}{P}
        a longer text\\
        a quit more longer text\\
        ... even much much longer text
      \end{tabular}\right\}
      & \textrm{explanation B}
    \end{array}
  \]
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I thought the OP wanted to keep the 'equations' numbered -- but just not as 1a, 1b, etc. Let's see if the OP sees fit to provide some additional information on this issue.

Comment: It was slightly ambiguous whether OP wanted eq. numbers or this was just a side effect of using a wrong environment. I agree I could wait and see which version is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

See, if you are after the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][l]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    &\begin{rcases}
    \eqmathbox{\text{text 1}}     \\
    \eqmathbox{\text{text 2}}     \\
    \eqmathbox{\text{text 3}}  
     \end{rcases}
        && \text{three equations}\\[1ex]
    &\begin{rcases}
    \eqmathbox{\text{a longer text}}     \\
    \eqmathbox{\text{a quit more longer text}}  
     \end{rcases}
        && \text{two equations}
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something iike this? (Note the absence of `\eqmathbox` wrappers.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{rcases}
        \text{text 1} \\
        \text{text 2} \\
        \text{text 3} 
\end{rcases}\ 
&\text{explanation A} \\
\begin{rcases}
        \text{a longer text}  \\
        \text{a quite a bit longer text} 
\end{rcases}\ 
&\text{explanation B} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: simple and effective ;-). +1