# add braces to a directory tree diagram

Tags: braces, directory

I'd like to add right align braces, to a directory tree diagram, for explaination but I don't know how to "mix" package command

here are the 2 links

[align right braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666873/align-right-braces/666891#666891)

[making a directory tree of folders and files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files)

in each cases, this is the last solution provided I try to mix

Yes it's exactly what I want but I struggle a big part of the morning trying to add a 4th brace so once again I required your help. Here are my modifications:

```
[system
  [config, name=config node
  ]
  [lib, name=lib node
  ]
  [Access, name=access node
  ]
  [Plugin, name=plugin node
  ]
  [file.txt, name=file node
  ]
  [templates
  ]
  [tests
  ]
]
\coordinate(top) at (current bounding box.north east);
\coordinate(bot) at (current bounding box.south east);
\draw[mybrace] (top)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 1}(top|-lib node.south)coordinate(A);
\draw[mybrace] (A)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 2}([yshift=-1mm]top|-file node.south)coordinate(B);
\draw[mybrace] (B)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 3}([yshift=-1mm]top|-file node.south)coordinate(C);
\draw[mybrace] (C)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 4}(bot);
```

[image: and the result:]

Comment: Where do you want the 4th brace? Right now your coordinates (B) and (C) are in the same place, so your brace from (B) to (C) is just a point.

Comment: I thought adding name=XXX node after an element of the tree, where XXX is the element name, make a point where begin and finish braces. So i try to regroup system with config, lib with Access, Plugin with file and templates with tests. and then adding \draw[mybrace] (B)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 3}([yshift=-1mm]top|-file node.south)coordinate(C);

Comment: OK. I edited my code again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enclose the entire tree in a brace:

[image]

you can use `\left.` and `right\}`:

```
$\left.\vcenter{\hbox{
  <forest code goes here>
}}\right\}$
```

On the other hand, if you want to separate parts of the tree with braces it's a bit more complicated. Here is a possibility using. the `calligraphy` library to draw the braces.

[image]

Use `name` to name the nodes where the splits occur. Then set `coordinate`s at the northeast and southeast corners of the `current bounding box`. Then draw the brace using the `name`d nodes. Since the north edges of the nodes do not quite reach the couth edge of the previous node, a manual adjustments using `[yshift=]` may improve the appearance.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm},ultra thick}, label={0:d}}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
      folder/.pic={
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
          (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
          (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
      }
    }


 \begin{document}

 \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        font=\ttfamily,
        grow'=0,
        child anchor=west,
        parent anchor=south,
        anchor=west,
        calign=first,
        inner xsep=7pt,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
        },
        % style for your file node 
        file/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) \forestoption{edge label};},
          inner xsep=2pt, font=\small\ttfamily
                     },
        before typesetting nodes={
          if n=1
            {insert before={[,phantom]}}
            {}
        },
        fit=band,
        before computing xy={l=15pt},
      }  
    [system, name=system
      [config, name= config
      ]
      [lib, name=lib node
        [Access, name=access
        ]
        [Plugin, name=plugin
        ]
        [file.txt, file, name=file
        ]
      ]
      [templates, name=templaes
      ]
      [tests, name=tests
      ]
    ]
    \coordinate(top) at (current bounding box.north east);
    \coordinate(bot) at (current bounding box.south east);
    \draw[mybrace] (top)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 1}(top|-config.south)coordinate(A);
    \draw[mybrace] (A)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 2}([yshift=-1mm]top|-access.south)coordinate(B);
    \draw[mybrace] (B)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 3}([yshift=-1mm]top|-file.south)coordinate(C);
    \draw[mybrace] (C)--node[right=2mm]{Explanation 4}(bot);    
 \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your, help it's close to be the perfect solution for me. There is just a little point that confuse me. In the solution you provide there is 2 braces split by: name=file node where "file node" is the label use to split brace 1 and 2. And, I am not sure a that but a box is created from north east (A) to south east (B) ie from point A to point B. First brace is draw from A to C, C is the element with the node, then second brace is draw from C to B.

Comment: @user20006686: The node `(current bounding box)` is automatically updated throughout the creation of a `tikzpicture`. So after the tree is drawn I fix those northeast and southeast coordinates `(A)` and `(B)`. The middle coordinate `(C)` should be directly below `(A)` but with the same y-coordinate as `(file node.south)`. The syntax `(A|-file node.south)` accomplishes this.

Comment: Sorry, Sandy I don't know what happened but the comment was half of my answered.

Comment: @user20006686: I edited my answer. Is this what you wanted?