# Adding equation numbers to aligned environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align, amsmath, braces

I need to typeset a text with several equations that: (#1) have to include the "maximize" and "subjet to" expressones in line with the corresponding equations; (#2) have to include three aligned right braces ; and (#3) the equations must be individually numbered.

After trying several routes (using optidef, rcases, plain arrays...) I found a clue in [Align multiple equations within right braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365909/align-multiple-equations-within-right-braces)

I've solved problem #2, and I've dealt with problem #1 by brute force, but I have no idea of how to solve requirement #3 (equation numbers).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ================================================
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[1][1-5]
%
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
      \text{Maximize:}\qquad\qquad          W &= W ( U_1 , U_2 ) \\[\jot]
      \text{Subject to:}\qquad\qquad      U_1 &= U_1 \left( x_1 , y_1 \right)\\
                                          U_2 &= U_2 \left( x_2 , y_2 \right)\\[2\jot]
                                            x &= x \left( K_x , L_x \right)\\
                                            y &= y \left( K_y , L_y \right)\\[2\jot]
                                          K_x &+ K_y = \overline{K}    \\
                                          L_x &+ L_y = \overline{L}
   \end{aligned}
   \begin{aligned}
      &\left.\vphantom{\begin{aligned}
         \text{Maximize:}\qquad\qquad          W &= W ( U_1 , U_2 )\\[\jot]
                           \end{aligned}}\right.\\
      &\left.\vphantom{\begin{aligned}
         \text{Subject to:}\qquad\qquad      U_1 &= U_1 \left( x_1 , y_1 \right)\\
                                             U_2 &= U_2 \left( x_2 , y_2 \right)\\[2\jot]
                           \end{aligned}}\right\rbrace\quad\text{Preferences}\\
      &\left.\vphantom{\begin{aligned}
                                               x &= x \left( K_x , L_x \right)\\
                                               y &= y \left( K_y , L_y \right)\\[2\jot]
                           \end{aligned}}\right\rbrace\quad\text{Tecnology}\\
      &\left.\vphantom{\begin{aligned}
                                             K_x &+ K_y = \overline{K}    \\
                                             L_x &+ L_y = \overline{L}
                           \end{aligned}}\right\rbrace\quad\text{Resources}\\
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
\lipsum[1][1-5]
%
\end{document}
```

Which gives this output:

[image]

Any hint will be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The `equation` environment will only ever apply a single equation number to the whole group.  You have already started to segment the structure using the sub-environment `aligned`.  Replace `equation` by `gather` (an environment provided by `amsmath`) and a separate number will be assigned to each of the `aligned` groups immediately below `gather`.  You'll have to break this up a little more, but the approach should be straightforward.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your feedback. I have tried several combinations of `gather` and `aligned`, with no success, though, I am unable to see the route I should follow. Could you elaborate a little bit?  Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overlap the 2 row entries using `\raisebox`.  (This is how multirow works, more or less.)

If you want to move Maximize all the way to the left, replace `align` with `flalign` and add an extra & to the right.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
% ================================================
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[1][1-5]
%
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\displaystyle \left. \begin{aligned} \mathstrut\\ \mathstrut\end{aligned}\right\rbrace$}%
%
\begin{align}
      &\text{Maximize:}&        W &= W ( U_1 , U_2 )\\[\jot]
      &\text{Subject to:}&      U_1 &= U_1 \left( x_1 , y_1 \right)  && \raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox\tempbox Preferences}\\
      &&                        U_2 &= U_2 \left( x_2 , y_2 \right)\\[2\jot]
      &&                        x &= x \left( K_x , L_x \right) && \raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox\tempbox Technology}\\
      &&                        y &= y \left( K_y , L_y \right)\\[2\jot]
      &&                        K_x &+ K_y = \overline{K} && \raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox\tempbox Resources}\\
      &&                        L_x &+ L_y = \overline{L}
\end{align}
%
\lipsum[1][1-5]
%
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for myself, I find that a layout with lots of curly braces runs the serious risk of chopping up the visual "flow" of the elements in the multi-line equations, making the material more difficult rather than easier to grasp.

I would therefore like to propose two entirely different layouts for your consideration. As a side-effect of rearranging the material, numbering the equations is trivially easy.

The horizontal lines in the following screenshot are there just to delimit the vertical extent of the `alignat` and `equation`/`alignat` groups. Still speaking for myself, I find the second layout simpler and therefore more attractive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{alignat}{3}
\text{Maximize}&\qquad&               &&          W &= W(U_1,U_2) \\[2\jot]
\text{Subject to}&&\text{Preferences}&\qquad&   U_1 &= U_1( x_1,y_1)\\
                  &&&&                          U_2 &= U_2( x_2,y_2)\\[\jot]
                  &&\text{Technology} &&          x &= x (K_x,L_x )\\
                  &&&&                            y &= y (K_y,L_y )\\[\jot]
                  &&\text{Resources} &&         K_x &+ K_y = \bar{K} \\
                  &&&&                          L_x &+ L_y = \bar{L}
\end{alignat}
\hrule

\begin{equation}
\text{Maximize} \quad W = W(U_1,U_2) 
\end{equation}
subject to the following conditions:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\text{Preferences}&\qquad&   U_1 &= U_1( x_1,y_1)\\
                  &&         U_2 &= U_2( x_2,y_2)\\[\jot]
\text{Technology} &&           x &= x (K_x,L_x )\\
                  &&           y &= y (K_y,L_y )\\[\jot]
\text{Resources}  &&         K_x &+ K_y = \bar{K} \\
                  &&         L_x &+ L_y = \bar{L}
\end{alignat}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: The thing here is that I'd like to follow, as much as possible, the original layout. No doubt that yours are good alternatives. Thank you