# Bracketing equations across multiple lines

Tags: equations, brackets

I'm sure this one is a hoary old chestnut that's been answered before, but i can't find that answer....I have set of equations (schematically) displayed thus, using amsmath:

```
\begin{align*}
a &= x1  &y &=1,\\
  &= x2  &  &=2,\\
  &= x3  &  &=3.
\end{align*}
```

What I want to do is put the second 'column' of equations (the "y=" results) inside a single set of brackets that spans all three rows.   Just can't see how...?

Comment: You mean like a piecewise function? Probably use `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}`.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47560/579)

Comment: Since there seems to be some confusion on your desired output, you might want to include a hand-drawn version of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short solution with the `[left=.., right=..]` keys of `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq} %% loads mathtools, hence amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left ={\begin{aligned}
  a &= x1 \\ &= x2 \\ &= x3
\end{aligned}\qquad\empheqlbrace}, right =\empheqrbrace]{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
y &=1,\\
 &=2,\\
 &=3.
 \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
a   &=  x_1 \\
    &=  x_2 \\
    &=  x_3
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\quad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
y   &=  1 \\
    &=  2 \\
    &=  3
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Here are some other approaches to this. The second one needs `\usepackage{blkarray}` in your preamble

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{r}
a   =   x_1 \\
    =   x_2 \\
    =   x_3
\end{array}
\right\}
\quad
\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
y   =  1 \\
    =  2 \\
    =  3
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation*}

\bigskip

\begin{center}
\begin{blockarray}{r\}c\{r\}}
$a  =   x_1$ & \quad & $y   =   1$ \\
$   =   x_2$ & \quad & $    =   2$ \\
$   =   x_3$ & \quad & $    =   3$
\end{blockarray}
```

Comment: Just the job - similar to tomacs' solution, thanks

Comment: @ionh Well I am glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.

Comment: @ionh Btw, first Tomacs' answer was different than mine. I posted mine and then he edited his.

Comment: Sorry Cragfelt! I was editing my answer, while you posted your one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
a &= x1  &&&y &=1,\\
  &= x2  &&&  &=2,\\
  &= x3  &&&  &=3.
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
a &= x1\\
  &= x2\\
  &= x3
\end{aligned}
\quad\left\{
\begin{aligned}
y &=1,\\
  &=2,\\
  &=3.
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- this is close, but I want the "y=" column inside a *pair* of brackets (that is, to use your model, there should be an opening brace to the left of the "y")...?