# Problem using \in within rcases

Tags: math-mode, equations, mathtools

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:cond}
        \begin{rcases*}
            % this fails
            % x,& foo \in bar \\
            % y,& baz \in baq
            % this works
            x,& foo bar \\
            y,& baz baq
        \end{rcases*} t\in[0,\infty)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Somehow, adding `\in` causes a `missing $ inserted` type of error. Any ideas why, how to work around it?

Comment: In the starred `<x>cases*` environments the second column is a text column and not a math column. Either use the unstarred `rcases` if you want the second column to be in math mode or switch to math mode with `$...$`

Comment: @moewe Thank you. Then how is it that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47562/22492) works?

Comment: As I said the second column is in text mode, `foo` and `barbaz` are totally benign in text mode and won't raise an error. You can clearly see that they are in text mode though, when you look at the output: They are written in upright and not in math italics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second column of a starred `cases*`-like environment defined by `mathtools` is in text mode and not in math mode (as the unstarred `cases` ones are). See §3.4.3 *More cases -like environments*, pp. 18-19 of the [`mathtools` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf).

That means that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    (-1)^n&=
    \begin{cases*}
      -1,& if $n$ is odd \\
      1,& otherwise
    \end{cases*}\\
    &=
    \begin{cases}
      -1,& n \in \{\dots, -3, -1, 1, 3, \dots\} \\
      1,& n \in \{\dots -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, \dots\}
    \end{cases}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

displays as

[image: output of MWE]

With the second column of the first `cases*` in text mode (no command is needed to make sure the text is typeset as text and not math) and the second column of `cases` in math mode (no error from `\in` and friends).

The difference is clear also in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    (-1)^n&=
    \begin{cases*}
      -1,& if $n$ is odd \\
      1,& otherwise
    \end{cases*}\\
    &=
    % don't do this!
    \begin{cases}
      -1,& if $n$ is odd \\
      1,& otherwise
    \end{cases}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the second example. The second column in the second lines is wrongly displayed in math mode]