# Brace after aligned environment is too long

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \varepsilon\coloneqq\frac{E_0}{E}
        \implies
        \left.
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            \varepsilon E&=E_0\\
            E_0&=k\frac{q}{r^2}
        \end{aligned}
        \right\}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

[image: a brace that at the top encompasses more than the aligned environment]

How do I make the brace only be as long as necessary for the equations in the aligned environment? I wish to keep the rest of the formatting.

Comment: How will the brace look like then?

Comment: @JouleV Like in Steven's answer.

Comment: Then the baseline will change... I do not understand the mathematical meaning in all that

Comment: @JouleV I want to show that the top equation is a variation of the more common form. The bottom is another equation and I want the brace to show I'm combining those two (result not shown here). If I leave `[t]` out from `aligned` then things look nice, but it seems as if the left-most equation implies the equation system.

Comment: Then your question is asking how to have a `cases` environment where the brace is at the right. It is already answered in

Comment: [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases)

Comment: @JouleV I'm not dealing with cases. Additionally, the `cases` environment has undesirable spacing and requires me to manually enter mathmode for the other side of the equation. Furthermore, I'd presumably have to use a similar hack as in the solution to get it to line up as wanted.

Comment: I do not use `cases`, see my answer. Also, LaTeX is designed for mathematics, so please use it mathematically. Hacking should be always avoided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mathematically correct solution. Please use LaTeX mathematically. It is not supposed to deal with workarounds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\left.\begin{aligned}
\varepsilon\coloneqq\frac{E_0}{E}\implies\varepsilon E&=E_0\\
E_0&=k\frac{q}{r^2}
\end{aligned}\right\}a=b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely much simpler and semantically better. Surprised I didn't think to put the implies part in the environment itself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the brace wants to be centered around the math axis.  Thus, one option is to change the math axis of the preceding material by way of `\vcenter`.

Maybe this?

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \left.
        \vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle
        \varepsilon\coloneqq\frac{E_0}{E}
        \implies
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            \varepsilon E&=E_0\\
            E_0&=k\frac{q}{r^2}
        \end{aligned}
        $}}
        \right\}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an alternative approach in which the right brace is scaled to the content height, using the `scalerel` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools,scalerel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \varepsilon\coloneqq\frac{E_0}{E}
        \implies
        \scaleleftright{.}{
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            \varepsilon E&=E_0\\
            E_0&=k\frac{q}{r^2}
        \end{aligned}
        }{\Biggr\}}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is [not mathematically correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491943/brace-after-aligned-environment-is-too-long?noredirect=1#comment1242120_491943).

Comment: @JouleV I was not addressing (or even attempting to understand) the mathematical veracity of the syntax, but merely was addressing the OP's complaint that the brace was too long.