# How to put right brace to group cases without using math mode?

Tags: braces

[image]I want do put right brace to group two cases (mixed normal and math mode) but when I try something, it says that I can do it only in math mode. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a more specific example? Perhaps a sketch of the desired output could also help.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a complete example of code showing us what you are attempting.

Comment: Related: [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47560/5764)

Comment: I updated it with a picture. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Run `texdoc schemata`

Answer (score 0):

You could add text in math mode using `\text{}` command. With the help of the `mathtools` package, for the `aligned` environment, you could do it like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\left.\begin{aligned}
    \text{Kvadrat zbira:}&&(a+b)^2&=a^2+2ab+b^2\\
    \text{Kvadrat razlike:}&&(a-b)^2&=a^2-2ab+b^2\\
\end{aligned}\right\}
\text{Kvadrat binoma}$
\end{document}
```