# Writing reverse cases in Lyx

Tags: lyx, cases, mathematics

The basic `cases` environment looks like

```
{
```

However, I want to make it

```
}
```

I learned how to do it using just tex at [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases)

But how can I do it using Lyx?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is based on [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549177/12558)**

You can used the `insert delimiters` option in the Math toolbar. If the toolbar does not show automatically, then go to `View > Toolbars` and choose it.

First, make math box. Then click the `insert delimiters` icon in the Math toolbar---the blue square surrounded by square brackets visible to the right of the `Math Delimiter` window in this picture:

[image]

The `Math Delimiter` window will open when you click `insert delimiters`. In it, make sure `Keep matched` is unchecked, then choose the inverted bracket on the left and `None` on the right. You will then obtain this:

[image]