# How to change the direction of a huge bracket?

Tags: lyx, brackets

I could easily add this to lyx. But how can I change the direction of this bracket?

[image]

The code for this is the following.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
 & \textrm{}\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
 & \textrm{}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to place a rightward-looking tall curly brace to the right of the second column, or are you looking to reverse the orientation of the existing curly brace? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico  I am trying to reverse the orientation of the existing curly brace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used the `insert delimiters` option in the Math toolbar. If the toolbar does not show automatically, then go to `View > Toolbars` and choose it.

First, make math box. Then click the `insert delimiters` icon in the Math toolbar---the blue square surrounded by square brackets visible to the right of the `Math Delimiter` window in this picture:

[image]

The `Math Delimiter` window will open when you click `insert delimiters`. In it, make sure `Keep matched` is unchecked, then choose the inverted bracket on the left and `None` on the right. You will then obtain this:

[image]

In that math box, you can insert a matrix of the desired size, e.g.  by using the `insert matrix` icon immediately to the right of the `insert delimiters` icon. You then obtain the desired:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `mathtools` and `drcases`

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{drcases}
 & \textrm{}\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
 & \textrm{}
\end{drcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to insert drcases in lyx?

Comment: you could add a handrawn sketch of tour desired output

Comment: handrawn? tour?

Comment: You can always directly insert tex code in lyx, under the Insert menu. It'll create a tex code box, in which to paste the code. That code is not parsed by lyx, but just passed on directly to the compiler.

Comment: @user42459 -- "tour" should have been "your".  As for "hand drawn", a sketch photographed on a smartphone and uploaded to your question would make it clear what you are asking for.  (I still find this rather unclear.)