# inserting a right brace within already-aligned equations

Tags: align

My question is quite similar to a [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases) question on inserting a right brace around a set of equations.  However, I do not wish to wrap the brace around the entire aligned environment yet I would like to maintain the same alignment throughout.

I would like to avoid a tikz-based solution if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** This example demonstrates that I lose the alignment I would like once I attempt to span *some* of the equations with a right brace.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{An ILP Approach}
A 0-1 model:
\begin{align*}
  \onslide<2->{
  \mathrm{maximize} \quad & \sum_{e \in E} w_e y_e  \\
  }
  \onslide<3->{
  \text{subject to} & \\
  \left.\begin{aligned}
  x_{il} + x_{jl} + y_e &\leq 2 \\
  x_{il} - x_{jl} &\leq  y_e  \\
  x_{jl} - x_{il} &\leq  y_e  \\
\end{aligned}\right\} \text{for} e \in E, l \in [k]\\
  }
  \onslide<4->{
  \sum_{l \in [k]} x_{il} & = 1 & i \in V \\
  }
  x_{ul}&\in \{0,1\} &\quad \forall u \in V, l \in [k] \\
  y_e &\in \{0,1\} &e \in E
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a small compilable example of what you've tried?

Comment: You wrote, "I do not wish to wrap the brace around the entire `aligned` environment yet I would like to maintain the same alignment throughout." This isn't easy to parse. Please provide more information about what it is you do want to achieve.

Comment: Hope my MWE does a better job of explaining my problem :-).

Comment: How the part with the right brace should be aligned is still not clear to me. Could you post a sketch of what you'd like to have?

Comment: Imagine the `\left.\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}\right\} \text{for} e \in E, l \in [k]` lines were commented out.  I then wanted to plant a `\rbrace` that spanned the three `\leq` inequalities.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
It seems that you looking for the following (showed is only last slide):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
            raise=1pt},
            thick,
            pen colour=black}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An ILP Approach}
A 0-1 model:
    \begin{align*}
\uncover<2->{
  \mathrm{maximize} \quad & \sum\limits_{e \in E} w_e y_e\\[2ex] 
            } 
\uncover<3->{
  \text{subject to} \quad &         \\
  x_{il} + x_{jl} + y_e &\leq \tikzmarknode{A}{2}     \\
  x_{il} - x_{jl}       &\leq  y_e  \\
  x_{jl} - x_{il}       &\leq  \tikzmarknode{B}{y_e}  \\[2ex] 
            }
\uncover<4->{
\sum\limits_{l \in [k]} x_{il} & = 1  \text{ for } i \in V  \\
            }
                x_{ul}  & \in \{0,1\}, \quad \forall u \in V, l \in [k] \\
                y_e     & \in \{0,1\}, \quad  e \in E
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[B]   (A.north -| B.east) --
    node[right=3mm] {$e \in E, l \in [k]$}
           (B.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: in comparison to your MWE observe that now the `aligned` environment is removed, right curly braces is drawn by help of `tikz` package and its library `tikzmark` and in MWE is only one ampersand per row. Hopeful they are now correct positioning (before math symbols to which you like to have aligned your equations). Also instead of `onslide` is used `\uncover` macro.

Showed result appear after two compilation.

Comment: This was what I wanted to avoid: the alignment of the relational symbols `\leq`, `=` and `\in` is lost once the inner `aligned` environment is introduced.

Comment: @healyp, this is not clear from your question.  See edited answer, if now it is as you like to have.