# Left aligned text in equations bound by right curly brace

Tags: equations, align, text, braces

I wish to have the following. There are several solutions on the platform, dealing with either left aligned text or rightly placed curly brace to the numbered set of equations. But, I am not able to produce both simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Especially the third answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47564/) seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Marijn If I understand correctly the question is also about getting the text `and` left-aligned. I think.

Comment: @campa I see, that is indeed different - however, it seems a bit unusual to put _and_ there, a system of equations always implies conjunction I think? Unless you want to contrast it with _or_ elsewhere or something.

Comment: @Marijn I completely agree with you that the request is somewhat odd. Anyway I'd wait from a feedback from the OP.

Comment: The format I seek is used by the journal Proceedings of Royal Society 'A'. At several other places, they put the left-aligned conjunction 'and' in the next line of the first equation of the system of two which I can obtain using \intertext{} in align mode.

Answer (score 1):

I propose one of these layouts, not exactly what you're asking, but with a simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\begin{document}

Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah. Blah.
\begin{flalign}
 & \text{and} & \begin{rcases}a = d\cos x \\b = d\sin x\end{rcases} & &
\end{flalign}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{equation}
\begin{rcases}
  a = d\cos x \\
  \llap{and\qquad} b = d\sin x
 \end{rcases}
\end{equation}

\begin{flalign}
 & \begin{aligned}\\ \text{and}\end{aligned} & \begin{rcases}a = d\cos x \\ b = d\sin x\end{rcases} & &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The position of 'and' (in the first layout) is left-aligned but not in line with the second equation.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: It would be complex, and in my opinion, it looks better between the two lines.

Comment: @Gaurang: I've updated my answer with a third code not too complex.