# Turn the single brace in the opposite direction

Tags: braces

How to turn the braces in this image to face in the opposite direction in LaTeX?
[image]

Comment: What's the code you're using to write this?

Comment: Maybe add a sketch on what you want to prevent possible misunderstanding? Doing literal what you said would be pretty weird.

Comment: The less-weird thing you might want to do would be [math mode - How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that one of versions 2--4 is that what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
 

 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
D_{it}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1& \text{if bank...}\\
2& \text{if bank...}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D_{it}=\left\}
\begin{array}{ll}
1& \text{if bank...}\\
2& \text{if bank...}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D_{it}=\left.
\begin{array}{ll}
1& \text{if bank...}\\
2& \text{if bank...}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right\{
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D_{it}=\left.
\begin{array}{ll}
1& \text{if bank...}\\
2& \text{if bank...}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]