# How to middle align contents of a single column only?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, nicematrix

[image]

I am trying to use `nicematrix` to provide good illustration of presented material with good alignment of entries explained. I want the contents of

> p1, p2, p3

to remain top aligned as shown. However, the contents of

> p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1

Must go exactly to the middle

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newlength{\widthWidest}

\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\widthWidest}{\widthof{weight of constant impedance, constant current,}}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{}r p[l]{\widthWidest} X[l, p]@{}}
    
    $p_{1}, \medspace p_{2}, \medspace p_{3}$ & weight of constant impedance, constant current, and constant power components of the real portion of loads & $p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1$
    
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{1-2}{\rbrace}
    
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (6.14 of `2023/02/18`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newlength{\widthWidest}

\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\widthWidest}{\widthof{weight of constant impedance, constant current,}}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{}r p[l]{\widthWidest} X[l, p]@{}}
    
    $p_{1}, \medspace p_{2}, \medspace p_{3}$ & weight of constant impedance, constant current, and constant power components of the real portion of loads & \Block[v-center]{}{$p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1$}
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{1-2}{\rbrace}
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason for using the whole text width; to the contrary, I see reasons *not* to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\auxlen}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[12][1-4]    
\[
\settowidth{\auxlen}{%
  $p_{1}$, $p_{2}$, $p_{3}$\hspace{6em}$p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1$%
}
\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{} l p{\dimexpr\displaywidth-\auxlen} l @{}}
    $p_{1}$, $p_{2}$, $p_{3}$ &
    weight of constant impedance, constant current,
    and constant power components of the real portion of loads
\end{tabular}
\right\}
p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1
\]
\lipsum[19][1-3]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different proposal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[12][1-4]    
\begin{gather*}
\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
$p_{1}$ & weight of constant impedance \\
$p_{2}$ & constant current \\
$p_{3}$ & constant power components
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\text{of the real portion of loads}
\\
p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[19][1-3]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to produce what you want using the `tabularray` package by inserting the curly brace as a vertical line of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newlength{\widthWidest}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\widthWidest}{\widthof{weight of constant impedance, constant current,}}
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\linewidth,   
        colspec={@{}r h{\widthWidest} X[l, m]@{}},
        column{1}={h, mode=math},
        column{2}={rightsep=0pt},
        column{3}={mode=math},
        vline{3} = {text=$\Bigg\}$}
    }
        p_{1}, \medspace p_{2}, \medspace p_{3} & weight of constant impedance, constant current, and constant power components of the real portion of loads & p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```