# Centering vertically specific rows

Tags: tables

I have a table, but some rows are bigger than others, because height of some has been changed due to `p{2cm}`. In these cases it would be wise to have rows centered. Suggested solution is to use `\arraystretch`, but it's not feasible because it stretches even these rows which do not need any changes, making already huge tables unnecessarily bigger.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}||c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Some text} \\
\cline{2-6}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\hline
Row 1 & val1 & val2 & val2 & val3 & val4 \\
\hline
Row 2 but this one is very long & val1 centered & val2 centered & val2 centered & val3 centered & val4 centered \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{table} \label{lbl}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `m` not `p`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, I knew there was easy solution to this. I have seen alternative solutions but they were like 500 lines each and I refused to believe it was the only way.

Comment: Related topic
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632992/how-to-middle-align-contents-of-a-single-column-only/675872#675872

Comment: Off-topic: `\multirow{2}{*}{}` does nothing useful; omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering @DavidCarlisle comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % it is part of LaTeX, you not need to load anymore
%\usepackage{float}           % not used
%\usepackage{makecell}        % not used  
\usepackage{array}            % needed for define `m` column type
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\small
%\begin{center}             % table is nicer, if you replace it with `\centering`
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}||c|c|c|c|c| }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Some text} \\
\cline{2-6}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\hline
Row 1 & val1 & val2 & val2 & val3 & val4 \\
\hline
Row 2 but this one is very long & val1 centered & val2 centered & val2 centered & val3 centered & val4 centered \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{table} \label{lbl}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you can see, your table is wider than available space for text in page. To correct this, you have two options:

- increase `\textwidth` by use of `geometry` package
- enables automatic split cells contents in all cell in table. For this you should define `m` column type or use `tabularx` table, where redefine `X` columns to

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

or use `tabularray`package.

An example for second options which use `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}            

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, m, wd=20mm] *{5}{X[c, m]}}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Some text
        &   &   &   &   \\
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
Row 1 & val1 & val2 & val2 & val3 & val4 \\
Row 2 but this one is very long 
    & val 1 centered & val 2 centered & val 2 centered & val 3 centered & val 4 centered \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{table} \label{lbl}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]